# Redirect from URLs with Query Strings

Tags: 301-redirect

My old site had tens of thousands of no-longer-valid products with 
urls like `http://example.com?product_id=123456`.

They are all search-engine indexed and now resolve to 404 in Magento. I cannot possibly create a redirect for every single one.

**How do I get them to resolve to my home page?**

Comment: 123456 is product id?

Comment: @AmitBera yes it's an example of the product id.

Comment: please check, i have update answer

Comment: You cannot possibly? I have a client with 500,000 301 redirects entered. You *could* possibly; you're choosing not to. BTW redirects shouldn't live on forever. They should be terminated within 6 months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case,you can use [event/observer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) and on event `controller_front_init_before` fire an observer.

First i guess that **your old product id and new product id are same**.

On  that `observer check  query string`*($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])* `content`

**?product_id=productID** pattern `in url` then basic  of this `redirect to current system product url`.

### Example:

Suppose,

**Old system product url:** `http://example.com?product_id=123456`

**New system product url:** `http://example.com/abx.html`

my code  will be redirect  `http://example.com?product_id=123456`  to  `http://example.com/abx.html` using 301 redirection.

> 301 redirect, you will resolved SEO issue.

### Here config.xml code:

```
 <global>
    <models>
      <magento67130>
        <class>StackExchange_Magento67130_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>magento67130_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </magento67130>
    </models>
    <events>
      <controller_front_init_routers> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <controller_front_init_before_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>magento67130/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>redirectionProduct</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
          </controller_front_init_before_handler>
        </observers>
      </controller_front_init_routers>
    </events>
  </global>
```

### Observer.php code is below:

```
<?php
class StackExchange_Magento67130_Model_Observer
{

    public function redirectionProduct(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        return;
        if($this->_getQueryString()){
            print_r($this->_getQueryString());

                // Check query string exits in product_id
            if(strpos($this->_getQueryString(),'product_id=')!== false){
                /* get Product ifd from query string */
                 $productid=str_replace('product_id=','',$this->_getQueryString());
                if(!empty($productid)):
                $product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productid);
                 if ($product->getId()) {
                    echo $product->getProductUrl();
                     Mage::app()->getResponse()
                        ->setRedirect($product->getProductUrl(), 301)
                             ->sendResponse();

                             return;
                 }
                endif;
            }

        }
        //die();

    }
    /* Check here Request query string */
    protected function _getQueryString()
        {
            if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
                $queryParams = array();
                parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $queryParams);
                $hasChanges = false;
                foreach ($queryParams as $key => $value) {
                    if (substr($key, 0, 3) === '___') {
                        unset($queryParams[$key]);
                        $hasChanges = true;
                    }
                }
                if ($hasChanges) {
                    return http_build_query($queryParams);
                } else {
                    return $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create one little custom extension to redirect if product is not found in your database

here i have given working solution and its perfect worked for me

[How to forward all the 404 Magento pages to the front page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65515/how-to-forward-all-the-404-magento-pages-to-the-front-page/65518#65518)

hope this will also work for you.